# vba "error 91" when trying to click a button on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I can't figure out why i'm getting error 91 in the snippet of code below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
 Dim loa

    Set htmldoc = .document
    Set loa = htmldoc.frames("content").document.getElementsByname("SpreadsheetClicked") 
        loa.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click `**'error 91 block variable not set`**
```

**Edited html to include whole source:**
towards the bottom you'll see the input tags for the buttons on the top and bottom rows.

```
FRAME src="/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-home-frameset.wml" name=content>

<CENTER><SPAN id=oContentWait style="DISPLAY: none"><IFRAME height="100%" src="/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-wait-display.wml" frameBorder=3 width="100%" scrolling=no></IFRAME></SPAN><SPAN id=oContentMain style="DISPLAY: inline">  
<DIV class=filter>
<TABLE class=Outter border=3>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT type=hidden name=SubmitTP> 
<TABLE class=Inner cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 width="100%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR class=content align=center>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;TP</FONT></TD>
<TD noWrap align=left><SELECT onchange="form1.SubmitTP.value = 'True'; form1.submit();" name=TP><OPTION selected>ALL<OPTION>ALL*<A onclick="getUserEntry('TP','TP'); return false;" title="Click here to select multiple Providers" href="#">*</A></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Incr</FONT></TD>
<TD noWrap align=left><SELECT name=Incr><OPTION>ALL<OPTION>DAILY<OPTION selected>HOURLY<OPTION>MONTHLY<OPTION>SMONTHLY<OPTION>VARIABLE<OPTION>WEEKLY<OPTION>YEARLY</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Peri</FONT></TD>
<TD noWrap align=left><SELECT name=Peri><OPTION selected>ALL<OPTION>FULL_PERIOD<OPTION>OFF_PEAK<OPTION>OFF_PEAK_DAY<OPTION>ON-PEAK<OPTION>ON_PEAK<OPTION>ON_PEAK_DAY<OPTION>WEEKDAY<OPTION>WEEKEND</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;POR</FONT></TD>
<TD </TD>
<TD</TD></TR>
<TR class=content align=center>
<TD </TD>
<TD </A></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Class</FONT></TD>
<TD </TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Win</FONT></TD>
<TD noWrap align=left><SELECT name=Win><OPTION selected>ALL<OPTION>EXTENDED<OPTION>FIXED<OPTION>ROLLING<OPTION>SLIDING</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;POD</FONT></TD>
<TD </A></TD>
<TD colSpan=2 noWrap align=left><FONT size=-1>Daylight Savings <INPUT type=checkbox value=1 name=UseDST> </FONT><FONT size=-1>Show Active Data <INPUT CHECKED type=checkbox value=1 name=ShowActive> </FONT></TD></TR>
<TR class=content align=center>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Ref</FONT></TD>
<TD align=left><INPUT style="HEIGHT: 0.5cm" maxLength=12 size=6 name=Posting></TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Type</FONT></TD>
<TD </TD>
<TD </TD>
<TD </TD>
<TD align=right><FONT size=-1>&nbsp;Time</FONT></TD>
<TD colSpan=4 noWrap align=left><SELECT name=TimeFilter> <OPTION value=StartTime>Start<OPTION value=StopTime>Stop<OPTION value=OfferStartTime>Offer Start<OPTION value=OfferStopTime>Offer End<OPTION selected value=Active>Active<OPTION value=UpdateTime>Update</OPTION></SELECT> <SELECT style="WIDTH: 160px" name=TSpan> <OPTION value=Today>Today<OPTION selected value="This Hour">This hour<OPTION value="This Hour Forward">This hour fwd<OPTION value="Next Hour">Next hour<OPTION value="After Next Hour">After next hour<OPTION value=Yesterday>Yesterday<OPTION value=Tomorrow>Tomorrow<OPTION value="This Week">This week<OPTION value="Last Week">Last week<OPTION value="Next Week">Next week<OPTION value="This Month">This month<OPTION value="Last Month">Last month<OPTION value="Next Month">Next month<OPTION value="Today Forward">Today forward<OPTION value="Tomorrow Forward">Tomorrow fwd<OPTION value="All Past">Before today</OPTION></SELECT> &nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT class=btn1 type=submit value=" Enter " name=EnterClicked> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV><INPUT type=hidden name=NewColumnList> <INPUT type=hidden name=NewQueryList>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    window.document.form1.NewColumnList.value = ''
</SCRIPT>

<TABLE border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD align=center><INPUT disabled class=btn1 type=button value="New Posting" name=NewClicked> 
<TD align=center><INPUT onclick="openChild( '/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-transoffering-summary-popup-userrange.wml', 'UserRange', 500, 150, true );" class=btn1 type=button value="User Range" name=UserRangeClicked></TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT onclick=showTransofferingSummaryColumnsPopup() class=btn1 type=button value=Columns name=ColumnsClicked></TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT onclick="window.location.href='/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-path-atc-hourly-summary.wml'" class=btn1 type=button value="Hourly Summary" name="NEW ATC"> </TD>
<TD align=center><INPUT onclick=SaveQuery(); class=btn1 type=button value="Save Query"></TD>
<TD align=center><SELECT onchange=SelectQuery(); name=SelectedQuery> <OPTION selected></OPTION> <OPTION>Configure</OPTION></SELECT> </TD><INPUT type=hidden name=NewQueryChanged> </TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=6 align=center><INPUT onclick="openChildWindow( '/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-atcmonitordetail.wml&amp;Allow=1', 'ATCMonitorDetail', 500, 150, true );" class=btn1 type=button value="ATC/TTC Monitor" name=ATCMonitorAlarmDetailClicked> <INPUT onclick=OpenSpreadsheetView() class=btn1 type=button value=Spreadsheet name=SpreadsheetClicked> <INPUT onclick=DownloadCSV() class=btn1 type=button value="Download CSV" name=DownloadCSVClicked> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><FONT color=#ff0000>Selected time range: <B>2016-03-18 10:00:00 PD</B> to <B>10:59:00 PD</B> </FONT><INPUT type=hidden value=2012-01-19 name=SelectedUserRangeStart> <INPUT type=hidden value=2012-01-20 name=SelectedUserRangeEnd> <BR><TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
```

Comment: Set frme = htmldoc.frames(6)
           Set loa = frme.getElementsByName("SpreadsheetClicked")(0) 'error 438 object doesn't support this method

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `loa` like this

```
Dim loa As Object
```

Edit #1:

Here's how you can loop through the html document to find the frame named "content":

```
Set htmldoc = .document
Set frmes = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("frame")
    For Each frme In frmes
        If frme.Name = "content" Then
               Set loa = frme.document.getElementsByTageName("input")(1)
               Or
               Set load = frme.document.getElementsByName("SpreadsheetClicked")
               loa.click
        End if
    Next resultClass
```

Let me know if this helps get you any closer

Edit #2: This should do it

```
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim loa As Object, loa2 As Object

    Set htmldoc = .document
    Set loa = htmldoc.frames(6)
    Set loa2 = loa.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
    loa2.Click
```

Edit #3: Ok, I think I figured out how to correctly navigate the tags in a frame now

```
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim loa As Object, loa2 As Object

    Set htmldoc = .document
    Set loa = htmldoc.frames(6).document.all.tags("input").Item(1)
    loa.Click
```

Comment: Where are you actually assigning your `htmldoc`? Because the line `Set htmldoc = .document` doesn't seem right to me, unless this whole snippet is within a `With` statement. Have you tried cycling through the frames on the webpage until you come upon the one with the name "content"? I'll update my answer to give an example. And three, this is more of a statement than a question. `Frames` are by indexes, so `.frames("content").` won't work. I would suggest trying to loop through the elements like I'll show.

Comment: The snippet is within a with statement (with ie). I did cycle through frames and got the name content. Working with frames is new to me so i'm not sure what you mean when you say frames are by indexes.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another snippet for you to try. When I say frames are by indexes I mean I don't believe you're able to get a frame by it's name directly (like you tried doing by saying `htmldoc.frames("content")`. It would be something like `htmldoc.frames(0)` or `htmldoc.frames(1)`, etc. By looping as I do in my answer it looks through each index and finds the one with the name "content"

Comment: Also, you were trying to grab the wrong index when you were trying to click *SpreadsheetClicked* button with `getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click`. It should be `getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Click` because it's the 2nd *input* tag (indexes are 0-based, meaning they start at 0)

Comment: I think i'm getting closer, I found that the index for content is 6.

Comment: That's great. In that case see my second edit that I'll add right now.

Comment: And when you say *index for content is 6* I'm assuming it's the 7th element then. If not, then replace my `.frames(6)` with `.frames(5)`

Comment: I found that the index for content is 6. However, i'm now getting error 438. I tried using your code but that had the same issue, here is what I currently am trying:    Set frme = htmldoc.frames(6)
           Set loa = frme.getElementsByName("SpreadsheetClicked")(0) 'error 438 object doesn't support this method

Comment: I believe it should actually be `Set loa = frme.document.getElementsByName("SpreadsheetClicked")`, including the `.document.` and no index on the end if you're getting it by name

Comment: I tried it both ways, using your edit#2 code I got error 438 again at the "Set loa2 = loa.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)" line.  I also tried getting it by name with no success. I'm trying to figure out if I can use name "spreadsheetclicked" in your edit#2 code? Would that help specify what needs to be clicked?

Comment: Ok, try my 3rd edit. I think I wasn't getting the tag correctly

Comment: just about there! your 3rd edit did not give me any errors. the problem is that it doesn't actually click the button. so I played with the item numbers (your code has item(1). I was successful in finding 3 numbers that clicked on different buttons but not the one i'm trying to click. My guess is that the code is referencing more html than the snippet I showed. Is there a way to cycle through the inputs similiar to how you showed me for the frame indexes?

Comment: It sounds like you're not accessing the correct frame then (since there are only 3 input tags you show in the content frame). My first suggest is to play around with the frame index (or use the code in my edit#1 to find the correct index) and if that doesn't work and somehow you're on the correct frame you can use the same code (edit#1) to cycle through inputs. Just change the `getElementsByTagName` to "input" instead of "frame"

Comment: The buttons I was able to click by changing the input item # are located on the top row of a list of buttons on the webpage. The button I am trying to click is located below that row. The code is unable to click any of the buttons on that 2nd row. I noticed when I go to "inspect the element" the html shows the input tags for only 1 those rows. So my source code i posted doesn't show the input tags for that 1st row. Also, I noticed when I went to view source, each row of buttons were in separate tables. Obviously I'm new to html so I'm not sure how to handle this in my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: by the way I double checked, it does appear that all the buttons share the same frame. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the full source code? That would make things much easier.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I just added a more complete version of the source code. the last line in the html includes the button i'm trying to click (spreadsheet). thanks